# MS Excel User forms vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi "im kind of new with excel VBA. I'm trying to do something simple as creating a USERFORM1 in VBA and showing it when workbook opens. I've looked it up online but for some reason something is not working.

I open excel, go to developer, create a userform1, add some stuff to it.

I open code for THISWORKBOOK and under Open procedure I type

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Then I save it as Macro Enabled and when i open it, nothing happens. What is going on? I know this is a silly question but am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did you place that code? "[Workbook_Open procedure MUST reside in the private module of the Workbook Object (ThisWorkbook)](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm)"

Comment: @BruceWayne I right click on ThisWorkbook open the module and type the code there. I select WORKBOOK from the drop down and same with OPEN

Comment: Looks correct to me - check to make it runs manually by creating a test sub that does `Userform1.Show` - then run it using F5. Also - make sure it's actually in the file you saved - if you open the file (.xlsm extension) is it actually in your code? You have to open the file that ends in .xlsm

Comment: In the Immediate Window, (Press `CTRL+G` in the VB Editor), type `UserForm1.Show`. It should pop up for you. If it doesn't let us know.

Comment: @i didn't have macros enabled in Trust Center. All set thanks forlks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trust center I didn't have macros enabled. I did that and everything seems to work perfectly.